# Why after my server makes a connection with the client, it disconnects and closes, even without the client sending any request for action?

Tags: python, python-3.x, client-server, serversocket, python-sockets

my server and client socket codes do not interact as I wish they were, and disconnect unexpectedly.
the server is disconnected and shut down as soon as the client sends a message, and by the way, providing the error:
`[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`

Here are some of the code blocks of functions of the SERVER side:

```
def getting_info_from_client_and_decoding(client_soc):
    """
    function for creating a TCP socket so the server could listen for incoming connections
    :param: none
    :return: client_soc: for a later use in the main() of socket functions
    :rtype: socket object
    """
    # Receive message from the client
    try:
        client_msg = client_soc.recv(1024)
        msg = client_msg.decode()
        print(CLIENTS_SIDE, msg)
        return msg
    except Exception as e:
        print(SERVERS_SIDE, "Error occurred while receiving message:", e)
        return None
```

and this is the main() of the SERVER:

```
def main():
    client_soc = creating_server_TCP_socket()  # Create and configure the client socket
    while 1:
        client_msg = getting_info_from_client_and_decoding(client_soc)  # getting requests for info about Pink Floyd from user
        if client_msg is None:
            print(CLIENTS_DISCONNECTING)
            # UPDATE: removed line for minor fixing: client_soc.close()
            break

        else:
            users_choice = client_msg[:5]  # analysing the gotten message due to a protocol that i invented(ISN'T RELEVANT)
            users_wanted_action = POSSIBLE_ACTIONS.get(int(users_choice))
            if users_wanted_action:
                users_wanted_action(client_soc, users_wanted_action)

    print("server shut down...")
    client_soc.close()  # closing the sockets
```

here's also part of the CLIENT side code for a better understanding:

```
def sending_request_to_server(sock):
    """
    function for sending the created message to the server
    :param sock:
    :return: none
    """
    message = creating_request_message_for_server()
    try:
        sock.sendall(message.encode())
        print(CLIENTS_SIDE, message)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR:", e)
        time.sleep(1)
```

and of course the main() of the CLIENT:

```
def main():
    sock = creating_client_TCP_socket()

    # getting info from server - in this case a welcome message
    getting_and_decoding_server_message(sock)

    print(MENU_OPTIONS_PRINT)

    count = 0
    while count < 8:
        sending_request_to_server(sock)  # sending info to server - a request abt Pink Floyd
        getting_and_decoding_server_message(sock)  # getting info from server
        count += 1

    sock.close()  # closing the sockets
```

I'm kind of new to the subject of sockets in Python.
first, I tried to connect the server and the client for a stable connection.
after then, I wanted to send as the client a message to the server, and I expected to get a replay from the server, so it wouldn't shut down and I could send several messages in a conversation.
Sadly, the server shut down and I don't know why I didn't get any replay, or even why the client's message wasn't printed on the screen on the server's side.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the client socket after each message received in the server's `main()` function. You should only close the client socket when you're done with the communication.

Modify server's `main()` function like this:

```py
def main():
    client_soc = creating_server_TCP_socket()
    while 1:
        client_msg = getting_info_from_client_and_decoding(client_soc)
        if client_msg is None:
            print(CLIENTS_DISCONNECTING)
            break

        else:
            users_choice = client_msg[:5]
            users_wanted_action = POSSIBLE_ACTIONS.get(int(users_choice))
            if users_wanted_action:
                users_wanted_action(client_soc, users_wanted_action)

    print("server shut down...")
    client_soc.close()
```

Make sure to properly handle the disconnection in your client and server code to close the sockets when needed.

Comment: thank you for mentioning that! it is helpful in some places, but I can say that unfortunately the problem is still there - the server still disconnects after a client's request.